# How do I calculate the sum of the values in a count column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a pretty complex database and I am trying to execute a query that returns the sum of all the values of the resulting count column. I can successfully determine the count values but how do I determine the sum?

My code is:

```
SELECT COUNT(cause) as num_of_deaths
FROM deaths
WHERE rlist IN ('09A', '09B', '09N', '09C') 
AND ryear IN (SELECT DISTINCT ryear FROM deaths)
AND cause IN (SELECT cause FROM icd9 WHERE description LIKE '%MN OF%')
GROUP BY cause;
```

Every time I try to wrap my count within `SUM` I get an error saying 'Invalid use of group function'. How do I go around about this?

My resulting set looks like this: [resultant set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpsgD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT SUM(num_of_deaths) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(cause) as num_of_deaths
FROM deaths
WHERE rlist IN ('09A', '09B', '09N', '09C') 
AND ryear IN (SELECT DISTINCT ryear FROM deaths)
AND cause IN (SELECT cause FROM icd9 WHERE description LIKE '%MN OF%')
GROUP BY cause) as nums_of_deaths;
```

Comment: Then try SUM(1) instead of SUM(*)

Comment: Error 1248 : Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Well you've got it then, add an alias: SELECT SUM(...) FROM () as nums_of_deaths;